# universally open and connected fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $A$ be a coherent ring, and consider the map:

$Spec(A[[t]])\rightarrow Spec(A)$,

in particular, we know that it's flat. Is it universally open? Does it have connected fibers?

N.B: Easy if A is noetherian, but in general $A[[t]]\otimes_{A}k\neq k[[t]]$ with $k=A/\mathfrak{m}$.